# What percentage of stars would need to become Shkadov thrusters to move the whole galaxy?

Tags: space, gravity, megastructures, galactic

The advanced civilization in my story is trying to reach as many galaxies as possible in the next few billions years before the expansion of space has sent those galaxies permanently out of reach without some form of FTL travel which my story does not have.

I plan to have von Neumann probe-like self replicating machines powered by laser relays from Nicoll-Dyson beams, possibly a double beam from opposite sides keeping the star in its location whilst sending probes in opposite directions.

Once in the new galaxies the self replicating machines will gather materials and turn the majority of stars into [Shkadov thrusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_engine#Class_A_(Shkadov_thruster)), the collective thrust of the stars and the gravitational hold of the galaxy will move the whole galaxy towards the civilizations home galaxy.
 This assumption that whole galaxies can be moved was taken from the following videos: https://www.gregschool.org/gregschoollessons/2018/6/12/shkadov-thrusters https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VetAm7fCS0

My question is what percentage of the stars need to become Shkadov thrusters to move the whole galaxy? Would there become a point where converting more stars is taking more time than it is worth for the additional speed? The civilization isn't worried about the time the journeys will take, as long as the galaxies eventually arrive to their area of space.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This wouldn't work.

The big issue is that stars make up only a few percent of the Milky Way's total mass - estimates vary by a bit, but I've heard numbers in the 3-5% range. For instance, [McMillan 2011](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011MNRAS.414.2446M/abstract) claims about 4.98%. Dark matter makes up a substantial amount, as do interstellar clouds - i.e. non-rigid bodies.

The point is, even if you attached a thruster to every single star in the galaxy, it wouldn't produce any significant gravitational effects on the rest of the galaxy, and it certainly wouldn't be enough to move the Milky Way.

You *could* try and find a galaxy that 1) has an extremely low amount of dark matter, like [NGC 1052-DF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NGC_1052-DF2) or NGC 1052-DF4, and 2) is old and gas-poor, meaning most of its star formation is over and much of its mass is locked in stars and stellar remnants, not interstellar clouds. I'd have to learn more about stellar populations of these ultra diffuse galaxies to say anything intelligent on the subject, though.

Comment: oh no, those recent videos I watched got me hyped of the new story possibilities.

Comment: Well. If you attached thrusters to EVERY star, you'd get the whole galaxy's worth of stars.

Comment: @Andon True, but in terms of potential resources, it would be a pretty small fraction of the total available mass. Stars contain, optimistically, 20-30% of a galaxy's baryonic mass (depending on star formation rate and age), so you're missing out on a good chunk of things. Plus, that gas mass would be much easier to harvest, I think, than gas locked in stars. All you have to do to get hydrogen from an interstellar cloud is scoop it up, whereas starlifting (for example) is more complicated and less energy-efficient.

Comment: Thanks, thats interesting about ultra diffuse galaxies, I could still transport the stars and capture the gas atleast as you and Andon mentioned for the other galaxies.

Comment: Interesting question I’ve never thought of: If you take all of the stars out of a galaxy, is it still a galaxy? Can you have a galaxy of nothing but black holes and dust? What *is* the sound of one hand clapping in the interstellar medium??

Comment: More seriously: surely this is just a matter of timescale? If you turn every star into a Shkadov thruster then the galaxy must end up being accelerated (however slowly) In the direction you desire, right?

Comment: @JoeBloggs I'd think the stars would just end up reaching galactic escape velocity and leaving the galaxy.

Comment: Need you move whole galaxy, really? No would more simple move only the colonized star systems and leave behind the black holes, giant stars and rest of all?

Comment: @RodolfoPenteado It was the OP's requirement that the entire galaxy be moved - and besides, as I mentioned above to Andon, the rest of the galaxy contains a substantial amount of resources, too.

Comment: Good point. I kinda forgot leaving altogether was an option... :-/. If you’re willing to be inefficient a partial shkadov might work. Just enough to move, not enough to pull apart. Is it acceptable to wonder what the tensile strength of a galaxy is? Or should it be treated more like surface tension?

Comment: The civilization could move but they cant spread to different galaxies they will eventually never be able to meet up again, ill add the two videos to the question where I got the assumption that moving galaxies is possible.

Comment: @HDE226868 How do you know the moving stars would not drag the interstellar gas + dark matter with them?

Comment: @LawnmowerMan Space is big and stars are small. Most of the gas is nowhere near a star; if you start moving the Sun, a gas cloud two light-years away isn't going to pulled along with it. It's the old inverse-square law at work.

Comment: @HDE226868 why wouldn't it be pulled along? As far as I understand, the old inverse-square law predicts that the force applied by the star on the gas cloud is VERY small but not zero.

Comment: @Blueriver Just because a force acts on an object doesn't mean anything will happen to it - particularly when the object applying the force is moving away rather quickly. Sure, the cloud will feel a force from the star, but there are plenty of other forces acting on it (e.g. other clouds, the gravitational force from the galaxy itself, etc.).

Comment: @HDE226868 How does one gather the hydrogen floating as gas in space? You'd have to fly a ship around, and that gas would be so diffuse that it couldn't even power that ship. Collecting that material via starlifting is guaranteed to more efficient.

Comment: @JoeBloggs Galaxies form inside [Dark Matter Halos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter_halo) and a clump of matter contained in a DMH but has few stars is called a [dark galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_galaxy).  DMHs are thought to have been the first large structures in the universe, creating galaxies within them by attracting dust and gas which then clumped under its own gravity int stars. If you removed all the stars from a halo the halo would likely spawn new stars over time.

Comment: @HDE226868 how does removing the second mention of NGC 1052-DF2 deviate from the original intent of your post?

Comment: @TheCommander I think there's a miscommunication. I didn't mention it twice -- that "2)" is just the start of the second set of characteristics the galaxy should. Sorry about the confusion! I've put a comma after "NGC 1052-DF4" to make it clearer.